# Ignore static files in Url Rewrite module IIS (7.xx)

Tags: iis-7, mapping, url-rewriting

I have already been through the related questions and couldn't find anything that'd help. So here is my question.

The shared servers where my site is uploaded are being updated and they recently installed the latest IIS (7.5 I think). They installed the Rewrite Module as well.

Before this update I used wildcard (through aspnet_isapi filter) mapping to rewrite paths like 
mysite.com/contact
to
mysite.com/pages/contact.aspx

Now, I am required to use the  in the configuration file but the regex is giving me a headache.

I want to redirect all the 
.aspx files to
pages/[filename].aspx

but ignore the ones that are static files like
.css, .jpg, .png etc

I end up using:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="wildcard">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="pages/{R:1}.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Using the above the following works:
mysite.com/contact
etc
but these not
mysite.com/contact/
mysite.com/css/style.css
mysite.com/
etc

Can somebody help?
Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the "Is Not File" and "Is Not Directory" conditions?

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

Comment: Sorry for accepting this as an answer after 8 long years. I have been away from the site for so long and just re-activated my account. I don't even remember what solved this problem but I am sure your answer helped. Thanks